# Kill current application bypassing close events

Tags: vb.net

Is there an easy way to kill the running application without firing any of its registered FormClose or ApplicationExit events ? Something like selecting the process in task manager and killing it from there ?

I know that this is not the "clean" way, and i know you should use `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()` or `Me.Close`, but in this case i realy need to do it the "dirty" way!

Only thing i can think of currently is getting the name of the process of my application and the using `System.Diagnostics.Process` to get the instance and calling kill on it. But it would be nice to have an easier way.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Because the events that are registered for application close are not supposed to run in this case.

Comment: You can simply use the `End` keyword in VB.NET.  Exact same thing as Environment.Exit().  The rudest possible way is Environment.FailFast(), not even the finalizers run.

Comment: Doesn't Enviroment.Exit fire the ApplicationClose events ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, `Process` has a function to get the current process.

```
Dim process As System.Diagnostics.Process = process.GetCurrentProcess
process.Kill()
```

Answer (score 0):

If You don't want the closing event or closed event to run then you can also remove the handler.
Then thy will not run and the app will close without running the code in these events.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RemoveHandler MyBase.FormClosing, AddressOf Form1_FormClosing
    RemoveHandler MyBase.FormClosed, AddressOf Form1_FormClosed
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I explicitly said i want to do it the dirty way. I know you can remove handlers, but i am in an embedded API scope where i have no control over the underlying application events. But i needed to close the process without it saving some settings, which it does inside the close events.

Comment: @Ryu Kajiya you sayed ... Is there an easy way to kill the running application without firing any of its registered FormClose or ApplicationExit events ?